# How to simplify code to add numbers at the beginning and end of a list of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numbers which I want to split into separate arrays which contain only consecutive number chunks. As a second step I would like to add an x number of consecutive elements before the first and after the last element of every array created in my list.

This is the code I have come up as a solution:

```
import numpy as np

test_list = (1,2,3,11,12,13,24,25,70,101)
test_list_array = np.asarray(test_list)

#### add 3 items one by one at the end 
test_list_array_plus1 = test_list_array +1
test_list_array_plus2 = test_list_array_plus1 +1
test_list_array_plus3 = test_list_array_plus2 +1

### add 3 items one by one preceding 1st element 
test_list_array_min1 = test_list_array -1
test_list_array_min2 = test_list_array_min1 -1
test_list_array_min3 = test_list_array_min2 -1

### put all items together 
test_list_array_compl = np.concatenate((test_list_array, test_list_array_plus1, test_list_array_plus2, test_list_array_plus3, test_list_array_min1, test_list_array_min2, test_list_array_min3))

### sort them and get rid of duplicates
test_list_array_sorted = np.sort(test_list_array_compl)
test_list_array_uniq = np.unique (test_list_array_sorted)

### add consecutive items in separate arrays in a list 
def consecutive(data, stepsize=1):
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0]+1)

test_expanded_by3_no_cons = consecutive(test_list_array_uniq) #get new expanded list
test_list_original_no_cons = consecutive(test_list) #get original list
```

The problem right now is that this is not an easy to implement solution if for example my original list contains items that will get separated into arrays with a single number and to which I would like to add 10 consecutive items both at the beginning and end.

Any ideas for how I could change the code so that I can. 
1. first split the original list into a list of array of consecutive items (this I already can do). 
2. How can I write a function that will find the 1st and last element of every array and add an x number of items?

This would be a more modular approach to implementing what I would to do. I am just stuck at how this function would look like.

Comment: `np.r_` might be useful: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html

Comment: I had a look at the link and a couple of other stack posts and from what I can see np.r seems to be a more fancy concatenation method compared with np.concatenate. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code example

```
a = [1,2]
b = [10,11]
oldlist = np.asarray([a,b])
newlist =[np.concatenate([ [x[0]-i-1 for i in reversed(range(3))], x, [x[-1]+i+1 for i in range(3)] ]) for x in oldlist]
```

The result is

```
newlist = [[-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5],[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]]
```

Comment: I tried it now and I'm afraid that it doesn't work since I don't want to add [1,2] and [2,3] to every beginning and end of an array. Instead I want to add 3 consecutive items before the 1st element and 3 consecutive items after the last element. Sorry if I didn't explain this correctly. For example if I have a list of arrays ([1,2], [21,23,23]) I want to expand it to ([-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5],[18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26])

Comment: Thanks! This is a more concise approach to writing what I was going for! The second part of my question is how you would implement this if you were going to add lets say 40 items instead of 3 on each side of the list? Even with your new method it would be unworkable to write [x[0]-39, x[0]-38, x[0]-37 .....etc .... x..... x[-1]+1 ...etc x[-1]+40. See what I mean?

Comment: `[np.concatenate([  [x[0]-i-1 for i in range(40)], x, [x[-1]+i+1 for i in range(40)] ]) for x in oldlist]` should do it (i didnt check)

Comment: Thanks @esandier! This last one seems to do exactly what I wanted! I just tested it now.

Comment: I also tweaked the first range to make it reversed to have the numbers in the right order without having to sort: newlist2 =[np.concatenate([ [x[0]-i-1 for i in reversed(range(3))], x, [x[-1]+i+1 for i in range(3)] ]) for x in oldlist]